# Trouble with bitwise manipulation

Tags: c++, c, 64-bit, bit-manipulation

OK, guys, I know what I want to do, but I don't know if it already exists (as a function or theoretically) or how to phrase it, so I need your help :

- Let's say we've got a binary number : *(msb)*`10101110`*(lsb)*
- Starting from bit X, I want to zero-out all other bits (going left), as soon as the first zero bit is encountered.
- Do that as **fast** as possible, with the absolute minimum number of operations and CPU cycles needed

**An example :**

- Number = 10101110, Starting position = 1 (bit at place 1 = 1)
- position++ - bit at place 2 = 1, keep going
- position++ - bit at place 3 = 1, keep going
- position++ - bit at place 4 = 0, oops... zero encountered... now, everything has to be zero-ed out.

So, the final result of our imaginary function CROPLEFT(X,POS), where X=10101110, and POS=1, would return `00001110`.

---

Any ideas?

Comment: @MitchWheat Trust me, I've covered a whole notebook full of sketches for a wide variety of extreme bitmap manipulations. The thing is all I can think of this one includes a loop (which I most definitely would prefer to avoid).

Comment: @MitchWheat He says it's probably not the fastest way. And I agree with him.

Comment: @MitchWheat This is going to be performed some million times, so it'll definitely kill speed, that's why.

Comment: @MitchWheat Per second. (along with a dozen other calculations) :-)

Comment: @MitchWheat OK, no need to be secretive: It's part of my move-generation algorithm for a chess engine project of mine. So, if you've ever played with chess programming and bitmaps, you know what I'm talking about... ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Piece of cake.

```
y = ~x;    // We like working with 1's, not 0's.
y &= -y;   // Mask off all but the lowest-set bit
x &= y-1;  // Make a mask for the bits below that and apply it.
```

and with the position parameter added:

```
y = ~x & -1U<<pos; // Change 1U to a larger type if needed.
y &= -y;
x &= y-1;
```

The key ingredient is the second line and the fact that you can replace a value `y` with just its lowest set bit by applying logical and against `-y`. Sadly there's no such luck for getting the highest-set bit, unless you have a special cpu instruction for it, so you're lucky that your problem called for lowest.

Comment: I think you're missing the "starting at position X" part. Although it's a trivial change.

Comment: Crazy! Was that so simple? Yep, an explanation would be ideal; I'll test it and I'll accept it is asap.

Comment: @rici: Yes, I missed that detail. Is it okay to leave it as an exercise for OP? :-)

Comment: Yeah, need an extra shift somewhere in there. :P

Comment: Fine by me, although I already discarded my correct solution because you scooped me :)

Comment: @R..You make me sound like I'm doing some sort of homework... lol - but I forgive you... :-)

Comment: Hint: there's small change to line #1 that can add the desired behavior.

Comment: I went ahead and just added it.

Comment: OK, mate. Just tested it (with the shift edit included, for `ULL` though) and it works like a charm. Thanks A LOT! :-)

Comment: Btw, I've been programming for like 18 years, and - even though I've played with bits and stuff quite a lot - it never ceases to impress me how you guys could figure it out in a matter of seconds... Thanks again! :-)

Comment: I just immediately recognized it as a variant of the "find the lowest set bit" problem and went from there.

Comment: With that type of things, I'm more of the experimental type of person. So instead of doing it the obvious way, I have a tendency to experiment, observe and probably unnecessarily re-invent the wheel... lol

Comment: Actually, such a "get highest bit-set" instruction is available on most CPUs. GCC has an intrinsic function __builtin_clz that counts the number of leading zeros. It's easy to use and works on clang as well.

Comment: @R +1 for the -y trick. Note that strictly speaking it only works on 2 complement (OK, OK, that covers every machine I know of, not imaginary ones). I added my own answer to show that the bit inversion ~x is not necessary, we have enough operators to deal with zeroes or ones undifferently

Comment: @aka.nice: No, it always works. These are unsigned types. The fact that it works is the definition of the unary `-` operator for unsigned types, not anything about signed representation.

Comment: @R ah OK, modular arithmetic. When I see -x I always think signed, my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

OK, what the heck:

```
return x & ((x ^ (x + (1UL << POS))) | ((1UL << POS) - 1))
```

---

For what it's worth, both of them compiled with gcc-4.7 -O3. R..'s on the left, mine on the right: (using unsigned long and 1UL in both of them)

```
        .p2align 4,,15                          .p2align 4,,15
        .globl  zapleft                         .globl  zapleft2
        .type   zapleft, @function              .type   zapleft2, @function
zapleft:                                zapleft2:           
.LFB0:                                  .LFB1:
        .cfi_startproc                          .cfi_startproc
        movl    %esi, %ecx                      movl    %esi, %ecx
        movq    %rdi, %rax                      movl    $1, %edx
        movq    $-1, %rdx                       salq    %cl, %rdx
        salq    %cl, %rdx                       leaq    (%rdx,%rdi), %rax
        notq    %rax                            subq    $1, %rdx
        andq    %rax, %rdx                      xorq    %rdi, %rax
        movq    %rdx, %rax                      orq     %rdx, %rax
        negq    %rax                            andq    %rdi, %rax
        andq    %rdx, %rax                      ret
        subq    $1, %rax                        .cfi_endproc
        andq    %rdi, %rax              .LFE1:
        ret                             .size   zapleft2, .-zapleft2
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   zapleft, .-zapleft
```

Comment: I kinda cheated scooping you by only reading half the problem before I answered... ;-)

Comment: for x=10101110 and POS=1, this returns 10100000 (actually the opposite thing)

Comment: OK, just re-tested it. And I confirm : **it works**. Guess I'll have to run some profiling tests to see which version runs faster... Thanks a million for the all the effort! :-)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: I compared my version with R..'s, as a sanity check, using pos=2 and pos=31, for all 32-bit integers (so a total of 2^34 calls, 2^33 to each function). It took 17 seconds, presumably split roughly evenly between the two. So that's about a thousand million (inlined) function calls per second. That should be fast enough for you, no?

Answer (score 1):

```
CROPLEFT(int X,int POS) {

    int mask = 1 << POS;

    while (X & mask)
        mask <<= 1;

    return (X & (mask - 1));
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much identical to what I had written myself, but decided to avoid, because of that loop thing. Thanks a lot buddy, anyway... :-)

Answer (score 0):

replace trailing zeroes by ones:

```
x = x | (x-1);
```

replace trailing ones by zeroes:

```
x = x & (x+1);
```

**EDIT**: Oups, it seems I misread the question, above code zeroes the right bits, not the left bits !

To zero the left bit, we would need a final XOR operation:

```
y = x | (x-1);
y = y & (y+1);
y = x ^ y;
```

**EDIT 2** About the start position POS

We just have to zero out the rightmost POS bits in a first step.

```
y = x & (-1U<<pos);
y = y | (y-1);
y = y & (y+1);
y = x ^ y;
```

**EDIT 3** Above solution ignore the first group of zeroes if they are encountered at POS.
If this does not answer the question, then the code will be shorter, but very much like the one of rci now:

```
y = x | ((1U<<pos)-1); // fill trailing positions with ones
y = y & (y+1);         // replace trailing ones by zeroes
y = x ^ y;             // modify leading bits rather than trailing ones
```

Comment: Since I've got the checker from yesterday, I checked yours, too. It works :) It's ten instructions, one longer than mine but two shorter than @R's

Comment: @rici our code are almost the same, my additional step is probably a miss-interpretation of the question because i ignore first group zeroes encountered at POS